# How to match value from textbox to dictionary and display it in another textbox on button click with linq query in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, linq, dictionary

```
Dictionary<int, string> dictionary = new Dictionary<int, string>();
            dictionary.Add(04634, "AMBASAMUDRAM");
            dictionary.Add(04253, "ANAMALI");
            dictionary.Add(04153, "ARAKANDANALLUR");
```

Need linq query to get the key from textbox1 and match it to dictionary and displays the match value into textbox2 and this must be done on button click.

The below code is used without linq. And i need the same to done with the Linq Query.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string std = DoWork(Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text));
            textBox2.Text = std;

        }
        public string DoWork(int stdcode)
        {
            Dictionary<int, string> dictionary = new Dictionary<int, string>();
            dictionary.Add(04634, "AMBASAMUDRAM");
            dictionary.Add(04253, "ANAMALI");
            dictionary.Add(04153, "ARAKANDANALLUR");
            dictionary.Add(04371, "ARANTANGI");
            dictionary.Add(04320, "ARAVAKURICHI");
            dictionary.Add(04329, "ARIYALUR");

            return (dictionary[stdcode]);
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

var fooDict= dictionary .Where(a=> a.Value == "AMBASAMUDRAM")

Comment: linq query to display match value into textbox on button click

Comment: The Below code is done without linq query. Need Linq query to process this.

Comment: Do you want single record? what are you trying to match mean dictionary value or key

Comment: In textbox1 i am going to enter any key in dictionary (for example 04634). The linq query must match the key entered in textbox1 and displays the value (AMBASAMUDRAM) in textbox2 on Button_Click Event.

Comment: Please try this,  var foo = (from d in dictionary where d.Key == 04634 select d.Value).SingleOrDefault();

Comment: The Key must be retrieved from user, it should not be predefined.

Comment: if you want key from textbox then use this, var key = Int32.Parse(textBox1.Text);

Comment: But its not possible to define the variable in linq query

Comment: var key = Int32.Parse("04634");

var foo = (from d in dictionary where d.Key == key select d.Value).SingleOrDefault();

Comment: Thats ok but what about diplaying value into textbox2

Comment: Its Windows forms application

Comment: This works :))))))))) var key = Int32.Parse(textBox1.Text);
            
            var foo = (from d in dictionary where d.Key == key  select d.Value).SingleOrDefault();
            textBox2.Text = foo;

Answer (score 1):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
      // Use a dictionary with an int key.
      Dictionary<int, string> dictionary = new Dictionary<int, string>();
        dictionary.Add(04634, "AMBASAMUDRAM");
        dictionary.Add(04253, "ANAMALI");
        dictionary.Add(04153, "ARAKANDANALLUR");
        // You can look up the int in the dictionary.
        if (dictionary.ContainsKey(04634))
        {
            String value = dictionary[04634];
            Console.WriteLine(value);
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
AMBASAMUDRAM
```

**Using LINQ:**

```
Dictionary<int, string> dictionary = new Dictionary<int, string>();
    dictionary.Add(04634, "AMBASAMUDRAM");
    dictionary.Add(04253, "ANAMALI");
    dictionary.Add(04153, "ARAKANDANALLUR");

var value = dictionary.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.Key.Contains(04634)).Value; 
Console.WriteLine(value);
```

**Output:**

```
AMBASAMUDRAM
```

Comment: but the key must be retrived from user. thanks a lot.

Comment: @SAN, Yes you could pass the Key value hot coded instead of 04634 to textbox value